# Postgres Check for JSON keys

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm currently working with a postgres database, but my knowledge is limited to SQL. I am working with an orders database and need to select all customers who have purchased a selection of products. My table looks as follows:

```
order_id      customer_name   products_ordered
1             a               {"apples":3, "pears":4}
2             b               {"apples":4, "pears":4, "oranges":2}
3             c               {"apples":2, "oranges":3}
4             a               {"apples": 5}
5             c               {"oranges": 4}
6             a               {"oranges":1}
```

I need to check which customers have at some point ordered each product, apples, pears and oranges, so the output should be as follows:

```
customer_name
a
b
```

I have zero experience with accessing JSON objects in databases and I am wondering how I can retrieve a list of customers who have at some point placed an order for *[list of keys]*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of doing all that (now and every time you plan on manipulating the data in that field), have you thought about changing your schema to make storing JSON unnecessary?

Comment: Unfortunately someone else maintains this database and I'm simply doing data analysis on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the prettiest query, but it'll work.

Extract the json keys into their own records, aggregate the records by customer name and then do an array-contains comparison. Somewhat abusing CTEs to do this though...

```
with
    __customer_products as(
        select
            customer_name,
            json_object_keys(products_ordered) as product_key
        from
            orders
    ),
    __customer_products_merged as(
        select
            customer_name,
            array_agg(product_key) as product_keys
        from
            __customer_products
        group by
            customer_name
    )
select
    customer_name
from
    __customer_products_merged
where
    product_keys @> array['apples', 'pears', 'oranges']
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. Could you, if you have the time, briefly explain each subquery?

Comment: To be pedantic, they're CTE's, not subqueries - essentially inline temporary tables. The best way to understand what each one does is just to replace the last bit of the query with e.g. `select * from __customer_products`. I shall try and explain anyway: __customer_products gets the customer name and a setof json key names, so `(a, {"apples":3, "pears":4})` becomes `(a, apples), (a, pears)`. __customer_products_merged then aggregates these based on customer_name, so the above becomes `(a, [apples, pears])`. The reason for all this is so that the array-contains operator `@>` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple query if you are willing to create a custom aggregate function that aggregates multiple JSONB values into a single one, merging the keys.

First create the aggregate function:

```
create aggregate jsonb_object_agg(jsonb) 
(  
  sfunc = 'jsonb_concat',
  stype = jsonb,
  initcond = '{}'
);
```

Note that this is different then the built-in `jsonb_object_agg()` which takes two parameters (key, value). It uses the `jsonb_concat` function [`||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to merge two JSONB values into one.

With that aggregate, your  query is as simple as:

```
select customer_name
from orders
group by customer_name
having jsonb_object_agg(products_ordered) ?& array['pears','apples', 'oranges'];
```

The [`?&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) operator checks if all keys are present in the JSONB value.

---

Without the aggregate function you can do this:

```
select customer_name
from orders, 
     jsonb_each_text(products_ordered) as t(k,v)
group by customer_name
having jsonb_object_agg(t.k, t.v) ?& array['pears','apples', 'oranges'];
```

However this expands each JSON value into multiple rows for every order, just to aggregate it back again - this produces a bigger intermediate result than the "real" aggregate function, so it might be slower.

Online example: http://rextester.com/EAZVG14239

---

All of the above assumes that your `products_ordered` is a `JSONB` column. If it's a `JSON` column, you need to cast it to `JSONB`